# nvidia GT 440 issue after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia

I have a problem with my nvidia card. When I use nouveau drivers every things is OK, but when I install nvidia drivers it's not. Some coloured glitches appears on screen and finally computer freezes. Can some one help me please?

Comment: How you installed nvidia driver? Provide details to get solution

Comment: I tried additional drivers, and manualy, but still same issue:-(

Comment: commands please - details...devil is in the detail

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: unless you provide details - it's almost impossible to provide any answer to you

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? How did you install drivers?

Answer (score 0):

To find your graphics card driver:

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu# lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

It should give something like this

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] [10de:104a] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:2619]
```

Then refer to [this](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
which will give you specific driver for your graphics card

then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

then(below example is for nvidia-361 -yours might be different)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

**Note : In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their website the one which is some what like `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` you need to uninstall that first...just follow the directions to uninstall it first.**

Comment: `nvidia-current` is not the latest, but an old legacy driver. And xorg-edgers is wrong.

Comment: On nvidia site it says that I need nvidia-361.28 (I have nvidia GT 440), but when I trying to install it from terminal it says that ther's no nvidia-361.

Comment: this will work 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot'

Comment: Why do you suggest drivers from ppa?

Comment: @Pilot6. In my case I was always able to install the driver directly from nvidia site(NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run) but it ended up in login loop and other issues. ppa approach worked for me fine-in both the machines.

Comment: It works most of the times, but it is not a recommended solution for a newbie.

Comment: @user283289. what's error message?

Comment: @user283289. Plz read the full answer. i don't think you did this 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update' if 361 is not found - you should get some detailed message OR try 358

Comment: @Ashu sorry for that, but I forgot about update command. Now It works, but after installing nvidia-361 driver I still have glithes and my computer freezes. So I thing my card is broken... Anyway thanks for help.